# Using Jquery To Toggle Elements

Tags: jquery

I am using JQUery 1.7.1 to toggle a div named .interest-group. When you click a link it opens the next div named .interest-group. Right now, you can toggle all of the .interest-group divs to be visible, but I would like to make it that only one can be visible at a time. How can I do this?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/DWwKs/6/

Here is my JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.interest').toggle(

    function () {
        $(this).next('.interest-group').show();
    },

    function () {
        $(this).next('.interest-group').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Toggle don't get function as first argument (as far as i know): http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 2):

That version of toggle() was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, and removed in 1.9, try this instead :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.interest').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.interest-group').hide();
        $(this).next('.interest-group').toggle();
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/DWwKs/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/DWwKs/8/

Just add the `$('.interest-group').hide();` to the first function